# Is this Arma(2,1) model Stationary, Causal or both?

Tags: statistics, time-series, stationary-processes

When I did this problem I came to a different conclusion because one of my roots was inside the unit circle and therefore the model is only stationary. Am I wrong or is the book wrong?

[image]

Comment: The book is correct: both roots lie outside the unit circle.

Comment: Great details @ki3i